# How to extensively configure an Ember.Component

Tags: ember.js

I am creating an Ember.Component which displays a CRUD table. As the component shall be reusable it needs a lot configuration, such as columns to display, pagination options, etc. ...

At the moment I am inserting the component using handlebars:

```
<div class="some-div">
    {{power-table items=this.model columns='...'}}
</div>
```

I wouldn't want to use this nice way of inserting a component. However, it is pot really possible to extensively configure a component here, is it? I found out it's not even possible to pass an object as parameter, e.g. the following it not possible:

```
<div class="some-div">
    {{power-table items=this.model columns=[id, name, foo, bar] }}
</div>
```

How and where should I configure the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that instead of setting columns=[id,name,foo,bar] in the handlebar like this:

```
<div class="some-div">
{{power-table items=this.model columns=[id, name, foo, bar] }}
</div>
```

You can set the columns property in the controller for the handlebar template and use the name of the property in the handlebar file. So all the logic would come from the controller and the handlebar would just tell which property is accessible in the component and by what name. So the controller for the enclosing template would be the best place to heavily configure the component. Have a look at the following page for more info:
http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/
I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Also if you don't want to create your own component for the purpose of displaying data in a table with pagination and sorting etc, you can have a look at jquery datatables plugin. It's pretty easy to integrate with Ember and has a lot of options to customize. https://datatables.net/